Mollification and Pointwise Evaluation of Tempered Distributions in the Complex Plane
In the context of tempered distributions in the complex plane, I am trying to understand how to perform pointwise evaluations of a distribution that is a combination of Dirac delta functions and smooth functions. Specifically, I am interested in using a mollification or limiting procedure to approximate such distributions and allow for well-defined point evaluations.
For example, consider a tempered distribution of the form:
$$
T(z) = w \delta(z - z_0) + g(z)
$$
where $w$ is a constant, $\delta(z - z_0)$ is the Dirac delta function centered at $z_0$, and $g(z)$ is a smooth function. My understanding is that mollification involves convolving $T(z)$ with a smooth mollifier $\varphi_\epsilon(z)$, where $\epsilon > 0$ controls the "width" of the mollifier. The goal is to obtain a smooth approximation $T_\epsilon(z)$ that converges to $T(z)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$.
Here are the steps I have in mind:

Choose a mollifier $\varphi_\epsilon(z)$, such as a bump function that is smooth and compactly supported, for example:
$$
   \varphi_\epsilon(z) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \varphi\left(\frac{z}{\epsilon}\right)
   $$
where $\varphi(z)$ is a smooth function with compact support, normalized so that $\int_{\mathbb{C}} \varphi(z) \, dA = 1$, and $\varphi(z)$ is non-negative and vanishes outside a ball of radius 1.

Compute the mollified distribution:
$$
   T_\epsilon(z) = (T \ast \varphi_\epsilon)(z)
   $$

Take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ to approximate $T(z)$, allowing for pointwise evaluation of $T_\epsilon(z)$ as a smooth function.


Questions:

Is this mollification procedure correct for evaluating tempered distributions that include both delta functions and smooth components in the complex plane?
What are the necessary conditions on the mollifier $\varphi_\epsilon(z)$ to ensure the procedure works correctly?
Could you provide any references (textbooks or papers) that detail this approach for mollification and pointwise evaluation in the context of tempered distributions?

Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!

Tags: tempered-distributions, complex-analysis, mollification, dirac-delta, convolution

The definition of $T_\varepsilon$ you gave is the standard way of defining the mollification of a distribution $T$. No matter what is the precise function $\varphi$, as long as you have the above assumptions, $T_\varepsilon$ are smooth functions and converge to $T$ in the space of distributions. This is true for any distribution $T$.
The point is that in general, the (continuously parametrized) sequence $T_\varepsilon$ does not converge pointwise. If $T$ is the distribution you wrote above, $T_\varepsilon$ will converge locally uniformly to $g$ on $\mathbb C\setminus\{z_0\}$, and it will diverge to $+\infty$ at $z=z_0$ if $\varphi(0)>0$. This generalizes in the obvious way if you have a sum of deltas that is, for example, locally finite (there is a finite number of deltas in any compact region of $\mathbb C$).
In general, if you have any distribution $T$, you can define the “regular set” of $T$ as the set of points $z$ for which there exists an open neighbourhood $U\ni z$ such that $T$ can be represented as a smooth function when restricted to $U$. It follows from the definition that the regular set of $T$ is open, and it is possible to show that $T$ is smooth on the whole regular set, and $T_\varepsilon$ converges locally uniformly to $T$ (it also works by replacing “smooth” by “continuous” in the definition of the regular set). But in general, $T_\varepsilon$ does not necessarily converge pointwise on the complement of the regular set, and/or the limit might depend on how you choose the mollifier $\varphi$.
If you have a sum of deltas centered at diferent points plus a smooth function, the limits will always be $\pm\infty$ on any point in which the delta is centered, with a sign that depends on the coefficient of the delta, as long as $\varphi(0)>0$.
